# How to Select these record by MYSQL Statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a Table:

```
tblUserLoginRecord  
ID ||  User || LoginTime  
1  ||  Peter|| 2017-07-03  
2  ||  Susan|| 2017-07-04  
3  ||  Sam  || 2017-07-05  
4  ||  Sam  || 2017-07-07  
5  ||  Sam  || 2017-07-08  
6  ||  Susan|| 2017-07-09
```

I want to have a result that show the last LoginTime Group By User(Using ID DESC will be fine too):

```
ID ||  User || LoginTime  
1  ||  Peter|| 2017-07-03  
5  ||  Sam  || 2017-07-08  
6  ||  Susan|| 2017-07-09
```

How I do it now is:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tblUserLoginRecord ORDER BY ID DESC) a GROUP BY User;
```

But it will be much slower if the table growth bigger. How can I make it better?
Thank you.

Comment: You can convert the date into time stamp. After that, Use MAX() function to get the last login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select only once if you are using mysql. That will speed up things up.Also your query should be better. See below and use it, you will see the difference

```
Select ID , User, max(LoginTime) as date
from tblUserLoginRecord  
group by User
```

You need to build better queries for better results which will help beyond your expectations.

Comment: Yea!! That's what I want. Thank you.